# Android Studio: How display object package like in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

In Eclipse it was possible to hover over an object and a pop up would show the package the object belonged to. Like here:

[image]

you see that the object source belongs to com.google.zxing.... and so on. How can I get that information in Android Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it from **setting**. Go to **Setting>> Editor>> Other and check Show Quick Doc**

Check This:

[image]

After Changing it.

[image: Image2]